# Java Integers default to int

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I'm calling various methods and the parameters Integer values are all defaulting to int, even values such as 1 or 0, is there anything I should be doing to solve this, other than type casting? Here's an example of the code

```
public class Launch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CoordinateHandler handler = new Handler();
        short x = 3901;
        short y = 5921;
        byte h = 2;
        handler.toCoordinates(x, y, h, "modern");
    }
}
public class CoordinateHandler extends CoordinateMain {
    public void toCoordinates(short absX, short absY, byte height, String type) {
        if (type.equals("modern")) {
            super.toCoordinates(absX, absY, height);
        } else {
            coordinateUpdateEvent(absX, absY, height, type);
        }
    }
}
```

I would get a compile error saying possible loss of precision on the lines of short x, short y, and byte h, and I would also get a compile error saying toCoordinates(int, int, int, String) can not be applied to toCoordinates(short, short, byte, String)

Comment: Believe the compiler - change those shorts to ints and everything will be fine.

Comment: Shouldnt that be `public class Launch {` ?

Comment: According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) - it should be fine (`A literal is the source code representation of a fixed value; literals are represented directly in your code without requiring computation. As shown below, it's possible to assign a literal to a variable of a primitive type ... short s = 10000;` in the `literals` section) - maybe your compiler is on ultra pedantic mode?

Comment: Throw away the shorts and bytes. There's really no benefit in using them over ints, they just make things more complicated.

Comment: Wouldn't just using ints result in more unnecessary data transfer? I'm trying to keep this as program as stable as possible, it's a client-server program and I'd prefer the people using the client to have an optimum experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that these lines

```
short x = 3901;
short y = 5921;
byte h = 2;
```

result in any compiler error; same goes for the subsequent method call. This is completely legal and correct Java. You are probably not showing the literal code that causes these problems for you, such as assigning from a variable or parameter and not from literal value, which is automatically cast into the type of the LHS.

If you are indeed assigning from an `int` parameter, then the compiler is quite right: your assignment really may result in overflow.

Comment: Well yeah, the method is called multiple times and the majority of the parameter's values are specified as the method is called, there's a few occurrences where the value of each parameter is defined by a reference to other classes methods, but those methods return the correct data type.

Comment: Please then, show **the exact code** with the **exact compiler error**.

Comment: I found it thanks, there was a few things modifying the variables that I didn't catch.

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* the JVM uses ints for shorts anyway internally, so you may as well use them instead of shorts.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the JVM - it is all done during compile time, before the JVM is even invoked. (Unless I misunderstand the question, of course).

Comment: But by the time the code reaches the JVM it is using ints for shorts then?

Answer (score 0):

you're writing `CoordinateHandler handler = new Handler();`
Are you sure Handler() has the same method signature? I Think it should be `CoordinateHandler handler = new CoordinateHandler();`

Comment: `Handler` could be a subclass - and this is not all that relevant.

Comment: Somehow I think Handler is at the top of all the handlers.